# Tweet Compose OR Sharing Image On Twitter Using Fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am following this tutorial to share tweet + image on twitter.
https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/compose-tweets.html

Its working perfectly to share text on twitter with success and failure response but i am not able to share image, any one guide me what mistake i am doing here?

Note: when i share image from drawable folder of app it uploads, but i have to download image from Internet and then save it on internal storage.

**My commented code below of explains clearly that image is being saved on internal storage as i tested it.**

```
public void composetweet()
{
    File myDir = getFilesDir();
    File savedImage = new File(myDir + "/text/","test.jpg");

   /* if(savedImage.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(savedImage.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myTestImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);

        myTestImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }*/

    Uri myImageUri = Uri.fromFile(savedImage);
    Intent intent = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
            .text("just setting up my Fabric.")
            .image(myImageUri)
            .createIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, TWEET_COMPOSER_REQUEST_CODE);

}
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == TWEET_COMPOSER_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

               // onTwitterSuccess();

            } else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

               // onTwitterCancel();
            }
        }

    }
```

I have also tried:

```
Uri myImageUri = Uri.fromFile(savedImage);
  TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
                .text("just setting up my Fabric.")
                .image(myImageUri);
builder.show();
```

But no luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research i found:

- when you are saving data on internal storage from your app and try to pickup inside same app it will work.

But if you want to share that file created from your app in another app, internal storage will not give you permissions.

Hence i followed this solution to make that work:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mobitsolutions.socialmediashare.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/pathfile"/>
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image Uri should be a file Uri (i.e. `file://absolute_path` scheme) to a local file. For example:

```
File myImageFile = new File("/path/to/image");
Uri myImageUri = Uri.fromFile(myImageFile);
```

try to retrive image path with absolutepath also ther is one other option setting Twittercard.

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/app